# Problema con un registro trabajando con 2 tablas,en mysql

Tags: mysql, mysqli, update

tengo un problema en esta consulta, consiste en 3 hojas, una donde introduzco un email de una tabla para encontrar un alumno concreto, otra donde hago el cambio de curso y otra que modifica el curso de la tabla alumnos.

El problema es que tengo un fallo de Sintaxis según MySQL y no veo el error, os paso el código.

Esta es la página 1, donde introduzco el email del alumno

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Problema</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="pagina17.php" method="post">
        <br> 
        <label for="mail" id="e1">Introduzca el email del alumno</label>
        <input type="text" name="mail"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="buscar">
    </form>
</body>
```

Esta es la página 2, donde busco si el alumno existe y se cambia el curso

```
 <?php $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "base1")
    or die("problemas con la conexion");

$registros = mysqli_query($conexion, "select * from alumnos where mail='$_REQUEST[mail]'")
    or die("problemas con la consulta " . mysqli_error($conexion));

if ($regAlu = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)) {
?>
<form action="pagina18.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="mailviejo" value="<?php echo $regAlu['mail'] ?>">
    <select name="codigocurso">

<?php
        $registros = mysqli_query($conexion, "select * from cursosprog") 
                or die("problemas "
                        . "en el select: " . mysqli_error($conexion));
        while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)) {
            if (regalu['codigocurso'] == $reg['codigo']) {
                echo "<option value=\"$reg[codigo]\" selected>$reg[nombrecurso]</option>";
            } else {
                echo "<option value=\"reg[codigo]\">$reg[nombrecurso]</option>";
            }
        }
        ?>

</select>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Modificar">
</form>
<?php
} else {
echo "No existen alumnos con ese email";
}
?>
```

y aquí la página final

```
<?php $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "base1")or die("problemas "
            . "con la conexion");

$registros = mysqli_query($conexion, "update alumnos "
    . "set codigocurso=$_REQUEST[codigocurso] "
    . "where mail='$_REQUEST[mailviejo]'") or
    die("problemas en el select ggg" . mysqli_error($conexion));

echo "el curso fue modificado con éxito"
?>
<fieldset>
<a href="pagina16.php">Volver al formulario</a>
</fieldset>
```

[tabla alumnos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmmuH.png)

[tabla cursosprog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52QCT.png)

El problema que me da es este (lo de ggg lo añadí para localizar el fallo):

> problemas en el select gggYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '[codigo] where mail="alberto@outlook.com' at line 1

¿que error de sintaxis es?

Comment: Mira el value que optienes en el <select name="codigocurso">. Al parecer ese valor te está llegando mal.

Answer (score 0):

El error muestra [codigo] pero en tu codigo esta como [codigocurso],Teniendo esto en cuenta deberias de  verificar que es lo que recibe el archivo.php .

Bueno el error es porque se abrió una comilla simple y no fue cerrada,actualmente este codigo funciona ,he realizado una prueba y no tiene error de sintaxis.

```
    <?php $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "base1")or die("problemas "
        . "con la conexion");

    $registros = mysqli_query($conexion, "update alumnos "
     . "set codigocurso=$_REQUEST[codigocurso] "
     . "where mail='$_REQUEST[mailviejo]'") or
        die("problemas en el select ggg" . mysqli_error($conexion));

        echo "el curso fue modificado con éxito"
      ?>
```

Por lo tanto te recomendaría que verifiques bien tu codigo y compruebes si tu variables se tiene que llamar codigocurso o solo código
y lo vuelvas a probar..!
Recuerda que si la variable es un String debería de ir entre comillas.